# Create Bitmap image from pointer

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-c++, c++-cli, libvlc

There is a pointer to the memory in which the image lies in a certain format, you need to convert the pointer to a Bitmap image and draw it in WPF on a callback. How to draw I have ideas, but here's how to make a image out of pointer .

How can this be done?

Comment: Make the memory accessible as `byte[]`, then load a BitmapImage or BitmapFrame from a MemoryStream constructed from the byte array.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616046(v=vs.110).aspx